# Postfix Relay Access Denied, was working, no changes

Tags: postfix, smtp

an old time problem that I just can't seem to trace down to the cause.

I'm getting

```
Jun 24 16:23:05 mail postfix/smtpd[1496]: connect from mail-qk0-f174.google.com[209.85.220.174]
Jun 24 16:23:05 mail postfix/smtpd[1496]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-qk0-f174.google.com[209.85.220.174]: 554 5.7.1 <dan@devexnj.us>: Relay access denied; from=<user@gmail.com> to=<user@myserver.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-qk0-f174.google.com>
Jun 24 16:23:05 mail postfix/smtpd[1496]: disconnect from mail-qk0-f174.google.com[209.85.220.174] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

And all incoming mail from non-localhost is getting rejected. My postfix main.cf can be found below. I have tried various options for the smtp settings, but I can't stop inbound mail from being rejected. Strangely, I haven't changed any settings  and it was working just fine the other day.

All help is appreciate.

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

# Basic configuration
# myhostname =
alias_maps = texthash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = texthash:/etc/aliases
mydestination =
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 [fe80::]/64 46.33.82.220/32
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mailserver.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mailserver.com/privkey.pem
#smtpd_tls_CAfile=
#smtp_tls_CAfile=
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
tls_high_cipherlist=ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, LOW, EXP, MEDIUM, ADH, AECDH, MD5, DSS, ECDSA, CAMELLIA128, 3DES, CAMELLIA256, RSA+AES, eNULL
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/postfix/dhparams.pem
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs

# Settings to prevent SPAM early
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf,
    reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain

# SASL
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

# Mail directory
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/run/dovecot/lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhost
virtual_mailbox_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_alias_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/virtual

# Additional option for filtering
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# Milters used by DKIM
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action = accept
dkim_milter = inet:localhost:8891
dmarc_milter = inet:localhost:8893
smtpd_milters = $dkim_milter,$dmarc_milter
non_smtpd_milters = $dkim_milter

# SPF policy settings
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
myhostname = mail.mailserver.com
mydomain = mailserver.com
```

Comment: This Q/A will live longer than your pastebin. Please add your configuration inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
554 5.7.1 <dan@devexnj.us>: Relay access denied;
```

This error message suggests the `devexnj.us` is not within `mydestionation`,  `virtual_alias_domains` or `virtual_mailbox_domains`; the address is not handled locally, as it tries to relay instead.

From the configuration we can see that:

1. The `mydestination` is forced empty; no `$mydomain` here. This might be on purpose, so there's probably nothing wrong with that.
2. `virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhost` causes that you must have the domain listed in `vhost` plus the address listed in `virtual_mailbox_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox`. (The default setting of  `virtual_mailbox_domains` would require only the latter.)
3. `virtual_alias_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/virtual` with the default `virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps` would work if the address was listed in `virtual`.

If you have the address correctly in either of the 2. or 3., this may be the cause:

> `texthash` (read-only)
>
> A table that produces similar results as hash:
>   files, except that you don't have to run the postmap(1) command before
>   you can use the file, and that **`texthash:` does not detect changes after
>   the file is read**. The lookup table name is `texthash:filename`, where
>   the file name is taken literally; no suffix is appended.

So you have either

- removed the address and restarted Postfix later, causing the change to take affect only now or
- you have added the address but the change hasn't been applied because the file was already read before the change.

Check these files and restart when they are ok. I'd recommend using `hash:` instead of `texthash:` because that way you don't need to restart Postfix, but `postmap` alone is enough for applying the changes.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth explanation here. What I've come to realize is that I was trying to send mail to the wrong domain. I had previously used the .us domain for provisioning and testing and never destroyed the mx record for it after deploying. Once I realized I should have been testing .com emails, everything seemed to be ok. For context, I was trying to troubleshoot the tvial/docker-mailserver container but hadn't destroyed the persistent volume in between domain migrations.